"There is no registered service of type..." doing Dynamic Assembly Loading in .NET MAUI Blazor App
I need to implement a feature in my MAUI and Blazor project where, upon opening the application, it checks a server for a new version of the frontend. If a new version is available, it should download the updated DLL from the shared project and load it dynamically.
I have three projects: MAUI, Shared, and Web. All the UI is in Shared, and the MAUI and Web projects implement interfaces from Shared. I check if there is a new DLL for Shared, and if so, I load it.
This is my actual implementation:
private void LoadDynamicAssembly()
        {
            try
            {
                var dllPath = Components.Layout.DownloadLayout.GetFrontendFilePath();
                var assemblyLoadContext = new AssemblyLoadContext("DynamicAssemblyContext", isCollectible: true);
                var assembly = assemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(dllPath);
                var componentType = assembly.GetType("MyProject.Shared.Components.Routes");
                if (componentType == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("No se encontró el tipo MyProject.Shared.Components.Routes en el ensamblado.");
                }

                Logger.LogInformation("Componente encontrado. Actualizando la UI.");

                // Limpiar y cargar el nuevo componente
                ReinitializeBlazorWebView(componentType);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError(ex, "Error al cargar el ensamblado o el componente.");
                DisplayAlert("Error", $"Failed to load the component: {ex.Message}", "OK");
            }
        }

It's throwing the error:

'Cannot provide a value for property 'FormFactor' on type
'MyProject.Shared.Components.Pages.DeviceFormFactor'. There is no
registered service of type 'MyProject.Shared.Interfaces.IFormFactor''.

This is the DeviceFormFactor page (located in the Shared project):
@page "/device-form-factor"
@using MyProject.Shared.Interfaces
@inject IFormFactor FormFactor

<PageTitle>Form Factor</PageTitle>

<h1>Device Form Factor</h1>

<p>You are running on dll:</p>

<ul>
    <li>Form Factor: @factor</li>
    <li>Platform: @platform</li>
</ul>

<p>
    <em>This component is defined in the MyProject.Shared library.</em>
</p>

@code {
    private string factor => FormFactor.GetFormFactor();
    private string platform => FormFactor.GetPlatform();
}


In the MAUI project is the service declared:
using MyProject.Shared;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MyProject.Maui.Services;
using MyProject.Shared.Interfaces;

namespace MyProject.Maui
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            InteractiveRenderSettings.ConfigureBlazorHybridRenderModes();

            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                });

            builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();

#if DEBUG
            builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFormFactor, FormFactor>();

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}

And the FormFactor implemented:
using MyProject.Shared.Interfaces;

namespace MyProject.Maui.Services;

public class FormFactor : IFormFactor
{
    public string GetFormFactor()
    {
        return DeviceInfo.Idiom.ToString();
    }
    public string GetPlatform()
    {
        return DeviceInfo.Platform.ToString() + " - " + DeviceInfo.VersionString;
    }
}



According to your code, IFormFactor is defined in Shared and then registered in Maui Blazor. This may be due to process reasons, causing the service to not be registered when running to the DeviceFormFactor page. You can try to get the service through ScopedServices.GetRequiredServicein the DeviceFormFactor page instead of using inject:private IFormFactor FormFactor = new FormFactor(); FormFactor = ScopedServices.GetRequiredService();`.

Thank you! Now I have only the error No service for type 'Cashvend.Shared.Interfaces.IFormFactor' has been registered.. At least it's providing a value to the property. But I'm stuck now

You can refer to the Client-side services that fail during prerendering to see if you have registered IFormFactor in the MAUI, Shared and Web projects.

In addition, if you use ScopedServices.GetRequiredService to get the service, according to the example in the document, the syntax for registering the service is builder.Services.AddScoped<IFormFactor,FormFactor>(). You can try to modify it
